# How to check whether a matrix contains specific rows?

Tags: r, matrix

Consider that we have a matrix like below:

```
my_mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
```

And, we have another matrix `MM`, which has dimension 50x2.

```
dim(MM)
[1] 50  2
```

Here, I want to check whether `MM` has rows that are the same as that of `my_may`.

That is, I want to check whether `MM` has the rows `c(1, 3)` or `c(2, 4)`.

One direct way could be

```
my_mat[1, ] == t(MM)
my_mat[2, ] == t(MM)
```

But, in my problem, `my_mat` also has very large number of rows.

So, how can I do this compactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simply using `base::merge()` is enough to do what you want? For example:

```r
set.seed(123)
my_mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
large_mat <- matrix(sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)

head(large_mat)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    3    4
#> [2,]    3    1
#> [3,]    3    3
#> [4,]    2    1
#> [5,]    3    3
#> [6,]    2    4

any_common <- if (nrow(merge(large_mat, my_mat)) == 0) FALSE else TRUE
any_common
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you want to know **which** rows in the large matrix match, then a bit more work is required:

```r
set.seed(123)
my_mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
large_mat <- matrix(sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
large_mat <- as.data.frame(large_mat)
large_mat$row_num <- 1:nrow(large_mat)

head(large_mat)
#>   V1 V2 row_num
#> 1  3  4       1
#> 2  3  1       2
#> 3  3  3       3
#> 4  2  1       4
#> 5  3  3       5
#> 6  2  4       6

which_common <- merge(large_mat, my_mat)$row_num

which_common
#> [1] 14 23 25 12 13  6 30

any_common <- if (length(which_common) == 0) FALSE else TRUE

any_common
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `colAlls` from the matrixStats package.

```
> m_large
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    3
 [2,]    1    4
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    1    4
 [5,]    2    1
 [6,]    4    1
 [7,]    2    2
 [8,]    2    4
 [9,]    1    2
[10,]    4    2
> any(matrixStats::colAlls(my_mat[1, ] == t(m_large)))
[1] TRUE
> m_large[matrixStats::colAlls(my_mat[1, ] == t(m_large)), ]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    1    3
```

---

*Data:*

```
> set.seed(42)
> n <- 10
> m_large <- matrix(sample(1:4, n*2, replace=TRUE), n, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `%in%` along with `asplit`

```
MM[asplit(MM, 1) %in% asplit(my_mat, 1), ]
```

For example

```
> set.seed(0)

> MM <- matrix(sample.int(4, 100, TRUE), ncol = 2)

> MM[asplit(MM, 1) %in% asplit(my_mat, 1), ]
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    3
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    1    3
 [5,]    1    3
 [6,]    2    4
 [7,]    2    4
 [8,]    1    3
 [9,]    2    4
```